# Apache Wicket - HTML5-details-element on Repeatingview - save open-property

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have a repeatingview which contains HTML5 detail elements. The user can open or collapse some elements. If I remove some elements of the repeatingview and then reload the repeatingview by target.add(container), all elements are collapsed again. How can I solve this? Is there a simple way to store the open-Property?

Comment: could you post sample code?

Answer (score 2):

When a `<detail>` element is revealed, an `open` attribute is added to it.

You will have to persist that state somewhere: in the browser (e.g. in a cookie or just in some JS on that page) or send it to the server so Wicket can render the `open` attributes.

Comment: Is there a simple way in wicket to forward such attribute changes on the client side to the Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the `RepeatingView` in an `AjaxRequestTarget` but you are not overriding `onConfigure()` method of `RepeatingView` object, it will repaint and render as the first time it did.

Could you please provide some code so we can see in which context the issue is happening?